# Customisable ButtonSet in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like a google sheet dialog box (called from a macro) with custom buttons, ie ones that don't have the standard messages like yes/no/cancel as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/button-set) and would allow me to customise it.

There is the ability to output custom HTML from scripts, but I would need this to pass back values to the apps script (depending on what button the user pressed) and I don't believe it allows you to do this.

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Yes you can see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

Comment: In addition to @TheWizEd 's recommendations I strongly advise reading the app script guides in their entirety. You'll end up with a better overview of the platform's capabilities and features as you develop your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple dialog:

```
function launchDialog() {
  //build the html
  var html='<input type="text" id="txt1" placeholder="Enter some text and press save" />';
  html+= '<input type="button" value="Save" onClick="saveText();" />';
  html+= '<div id="rtnmsg"></div>';
  html+= '<script>function saveText() { var txt=document.getElementById("txt1").value;google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(hl){document.getElementById("rtnmsg").innerHTML=hl;}).saveData(txt);}</script>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Save Data');
}

function saveData(txt) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange("A1").setValue(txt);
  return 'Text has been saved';
}
```